# MouseEvent in TypeScript error not matching signature

Tags: typescript

I am trying to construct and dispatch a `MouseEvent` in TypeScript.
The `simulateClick()` example from [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) gives a compile error calling the constructor:

"Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target."

```
function simulateClick() {
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
    if (canceled) {
        // A handler called preventDefault.
        alert("canceled");
    } else {
        // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
        alert("not canceled");
    }
}
```

I have tried inserting a cast `<MouseEventInit>` before the parameter dictionary, but that results in the same error.

Even the following results in the same error:

```
new MouseEvent('click', <MouseEventInit>null);
```

Although it looks like it matches the prototype in `lib.d.ts`:

```
new(typeArg: string, eventInitDict?: MouseEventInit): MouseEvent;
```

Workaround:

```
var event: MouseEvent = new (<any>MouseEvent)('click',
    { 'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The earliest TypeScript version that seems to compile this successfully is 1.5.
The following works around the problem in 1.4:

```
var event: MouseEvent = new (<any>MouseEvent)('click',
    { 'view': window, 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': true });
```

Comment: nice, any idea if we can directly pass null?

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is correct. I tried it in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20simulateClick()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20event%20%3D%20new%20MouseEvent('click'%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'view'%3A%20window%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'bubbles'%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20'cancelable'%3A%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20cb%20%3D%20document.getElementById('checkbox')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20canceled%20%3D%20!cb.dispatchEvent(event)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(canceled)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20A%20handler%20called%20preventDefault.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22canceled%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20None%20of%20the%20handlers%20called%20preventDefault.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22not%20canceled%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D), even on my own computer (both TypeScript 1.6).

I would suggest to try to compile it as a standalone code snippet first on your computer.

Comment: Thanks, this put me on the right track of testing various versions of TypeScript. It reproduces in <= 1.4.