# How to implement Ctrl hold key and drag-drop in Cypress?

Tags: cypress, keydown

I have a feature to let users copy content when holding ctrl key and performing drag-drop. But holding the ctrl key does not seem to be working. Here is my code:

cy.get('body').trigger('keydown',{keyCode:17, which:17})
cy.get("@mysource").dragTo("@mytarget") //performs move operation without holding ctrl key (working)
cy.get('body').trigger('keyup',{keyCode:17, which:17})

This is not working....

Answer (score 1):

You can hold the control key in this way:

```
cy.get('input').type('{ctrl}test', { release: false }))
```

release:false will keep the control key held

[Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Key-Combinations) for key combinations

Comment: I am not typing in any input but just holding the ctrl key while performing drag-drop. This is my updated code ( Still not working): cy.get('body').type('{ctrl}', { release: false });
            cy.get("@mysource").dragTo("@mytarget");

Comment: This is working for me:

`cy.get('body').type('{ctrl}', {release:false}).then( () => { cy.get(source).drag(target); })`

Comment: I'm using this drag and drop library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@4tw/cypress-drag-drop
For your code, I think it would look like this: 
`cy.get('body').type('{ctrl}', {release:false}).then( () => {cy.get("@mysource").dragTo("@mytarget"); })`

Comment: Actually my drag and drop is working fine. I just want to keep holding ctrl key while performing drag-drop to copy an item and not just move it. I tried your latest solution but it is still not working. It just moves(drags and drops) to target and does not copy it into the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a mix between triggering a key hold like this:

```
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { keycode: 17, release: false })
```

And the solution for drag and drop I propose here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489164/11598855

Comment: I already tried this but not working. My drag and drop is working fine.