# Unable to perform drag and drop in Cypress

Tags: drag-and-drop, cypress

Unable to perform drag and drop in Cypress.
Here is the piece of code:

```
 it('verify user is able drag and drop a new widget from the widget list',()=>{
            cy.get('.ant-input').first().type(NAMES.widgetName).  //Search for a particular item
            cy.xpath('//div[@class="item-container"]//span[@class="column-drag-handle"]')
                  .trigger('dragstart', { dataTransfer });
            cy.get('div.items-sec:nth-child(3) > div.smooth-dnd-container.vertical')
                  .trigger('drop', { dataTransfer });
            cy.xpath('//div[@class="item-container"]//span[@class="column-drag-handle"]')
                  .trigger('dragend');               // <-- seleniumeasy listens for this...     
            cy.get('[title="CROUTON_WIDGET"]').should('have.length',2)
 })
```

Comment: I have edited the above as it was un-readable with the code not being in a code format. Also, could you provide the error message which would be ideal in determining the root cause. Have you seen this: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/issues/173 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361499/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-cypress-test

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@4tw/cypress-drag-drop

There is a separate npm library that adds this support to Cypress that you will need to install.

Answer (score 0):

Hit this command -

`npm install --save-dev @4tw/cypress-drag-drop`

Paste this into `command.js` file -

```
require('@4tw/cypress-drag-drop')
```

Try this script

`cy.get('.sourceitem').drag('.targetitem');`