# why is drag drop not working as per expectation in cypress.io?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, browser-automation

I am trying to automate a simple drag and drop scenario on a website .

https://gojs.net/latest/samples/htmldragdrop.html

I am going as per the method provided in cypress doc

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__drag-drop/cypress/integration/drag_n_drop_spec.js

my sample testcases is :

```
 cy.visit("https://gojs.net/latest/samples/htmldragdrop.html")
      cy.get('#paletteZone .draggable').first().trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })
      .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 500, clientY: 500 }) 
      .trigger('mouseup', { force: true })
```

After running the same :

cypress focussing on trigger mousedown the element i want to drag but on the step of mousemove -- nothing is happening when i check the same using "before" and "after" state . have tried differnet drop location just to ensure it was not related to x,y coordinate issue but in vain . please help

[image]

[image]

EDIT 1 : Able to drag-drop the same using a plugin available on cypress website itself i.e. '@4tw/cypress-drag-drop' . That worked like charm on the same website

```
  cy.get('#paletteZone .draggable').first().drag('canvas','center')
```

but when i tried the same on different website (used it for testing purpose only , i am not owning the same )  , there is a prob with that plugin too.
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html

```
  cy.visit("https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html")
        //cy.viewport(1600, 800)
        cy.get('#todrag span').first().drag('#mydropzone','center')
        cy.get('#todrag span').first().drag('#mydropzone','center')
        cy.get('#todrag span').first().drag('#mydropzone','center')
        cy.get('#todrag span').first().drag('#mydropzone','center')
```

On actual Website , draggable items on left side are removed and are placed on right Side , but after running my code - althought items are getting added on right side but they are not getting removed from left div . Is there anything we need to add here  ( IN my Screenshot - Draggagble 1 should not be present after code run )

[image]

Comment: It might happen because you don't explicitly give a `target_to_drop`. Looking on the HTML of your site, the source element and target element are part of two different blocks, so: `cy.get('#paletteZone .draggable').first().trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 }).trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 500, clientY: 500 }); cy.get(#myDiagramDiv).click().trigger("mouseup", { force: true });`

Comment: @AlexIzbas : tried the method suggested , but again on mousemove step -> before and after are showing focus on same point as shown in my screenshot. And nothing is happening after test is completed .

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    cy.get('dragNodeSelector').trigger("dragstart", {
      dataTransfer,
    });
    cy.get('dropcontainer').trigger("drop", { dataTransfer });
```

**This code is valid for me. I think it is useful for you. You can try this.**