# Cypress - Drag & drop - Angular CDK

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress, angular-cdk

Having a simple implementation of the Angular CDK drag & drop, with cypress.
Having latest versions of all packages, all the questions & solutions around wont work.

Basically, the drag & drop wont eve fire.

Tried with

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@4tw/cypress-drag-drop
- https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger
- Even with the answers to this "solved" question on stackoverflow [How to implement drag and drop in cypress test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361499/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-cypress-test)

But nothing would work.

Comment: For clarification: Was this Cypress 13 or already Cypress 14?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we found the problem, we manage to find the solution.

In a nutshell, the problem is that angular material - cdk, in latest versions, they are blocking the "drag and drop" from screen readers, for accessibility purposes. Which is ok, the problem is that the library / solutions posted, they were considered as "screen readers" as the "buttons" was 0 in the event.

In some of the cases, just by providing the "buttons = 1" would be enough, but that wasnt our case.

Because our case was a complex Drag & Drop where, you could only drag from the "handle" and you would be limited in the area of the list (so only move in Y axis) these solutions would not work.

The only & best solution that worked for US so far has been the following one:
Using the cypress plugin [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events)

```
const selectorForDraggingElementOrHanlde = 'whatever css selector u need'
const selectorWhereToDropTheElement = 'whatever other css selector u need'

cy.get(selectorForDraggingElementOrHanlde)
        .realMouseDown({ button: 'left', position: 'center' })
        .realMouseMove(0, 10, { position: 'center' });
cy.wait(200) // In our case, we wait 200ms cause we have animations which we are sure that take this amount of time
cy.get(selectorWhereToDropTheElement ).realMouseMove(0, 0, { position: 'center' }).realMouseUp();
```

Comment: Note using `realMouseDown` limits your test to chromium based browsers (excludes Firefox).

Comment: Im aware of this. Still is the only solution I found that works with the cdk drag and drop. If you know a better solution that works in all browsers. Please feel free to add it as an answer to this issue

Comment: Sadly, you've not given a reproducible example. Can you improve your question by adding some code? Better, a repo?

Comment: Cannot provide the drag & drop code. It belongs to my company. 
Still, as I mentioned in the question / answer.

Any drag and drop with the CDK latest and a "drag handler" should have the same issue @Yolandi

Comment: I have tested the plugin and it works pretty well with complex dnd-handler, multiple horizontal and vertical lists, and inside an Iframe... lovely!

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by [mmonteirocl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12727767/mmonteirocl)  above worked perfectly for me as well. I implemented it as a custom command in our commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('dragAndDrop', (subjectSelector, targetSelector) => {
    cy.get(subjectSelector)
        .realMouseDown({ button: 'left', position: 'center' })
        .realMouseMove(0, 10, { position: 'center' });
    cy.get(targetSelector).realMouseMove(0, 0, { position: 'center' }).realMouseUp();
});
```

Then called it the test like:

```
cy.dragAndDrop(subjectSelector, targetSelector);
```

Comment: You just copy / pasted my solution and provided it as "your solution" .... :( Its identical

Comment: Hi sorry this was not my intention at all. But I couldn't comment on your solution because of the minimum contributor score. Just wanted to clarify the exact implementation as I've used it, all Kudo's go to you.

Comment: It's also "noisy" - why assign the parameters to new constants?

Comment: Thanks it took me a while to understand the 'noisy-ness', I'm new to coding and Javascipt especially. I adjusted it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working when using drag placeholder without any additional library. I'm not clear on why I have to write this way but it seems to work.

```
cy.get(dragLocator)
  .trigger('mousedown', { button: 0, bubbles: true})
  .trigger('mousemove', { pageX: sourceX, pageY: sourceY })

cy.get('body')
  .trigger('mousemove', { pageX: sourceX, pageY: targetY })
  .trigger('mouseup', { button: 0, bubbles: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

this worker for Angular material cdk drag and drop

```
cy.get('.board-draggable-card') // draggable
            .trigger('mousedown', { button: 0, bubbles: true })
            .trigger('mousemove', { pageX: 10, pageY: 0 });

        cy.get('.board-cards-box') // droppable
        
            .trigger('mousemove', { position: 'center' })
            .trigger('mouseup', { button: 0, bubbles: true });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).